# how to find identical strings in a array of place names from a survey (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

This is my first time on here, so forgive me if the answer to this is obvious - but can't find a possible solution anywhere.

I'm trying to pull numbers out of a survey I want to set up, which will generate a list of cities. Thus:

```
var cities =  array ['city1', 'city2', 'city3', 'city2', 'city4', 'city1', city2'];
```

Will generate a list: city1: 2, city2: 3, city3: 1, city4: 1

Is there a way to go through an array like this in Javascript? The cities will not be pre-determined - ie people could be entering anything.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

tim

Answer (score 2):

Like Niet already answered:
You go through the list and put the keys into a object and increment the values.

```
var generatedList = {};
for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
    if(generatedList[cities[i]]){
        generatedList[cities[i]]++;
    }else{
        generatedList[cities[i]] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is spot on but I'd already started my jsfiddle attempt so posted anyway. +1 to you though :)

Comment: note: if city name has a space or weird characters in it, you can only access it using the array notation, i.e. `generatedList['New York']` instead of the normal object property notation, i.e. `generatedList.London`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "obvious"... if you know where to start. So here's the starting line:

- Create an object (literal, `{}`)
- Iterate through the array. For each item:

  - If the item doesn't exist as a key of the object, create the key with value 0
  - Increment the key on the object by 1

And... done! That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered since I started this demo but this should help you understand what's happening. Open this demo with the developer console open to view the output:

**http://jsfiddle.net/46wnj/**

```
var cities = new Array('city1', 'city2', 'city3', 'city2', 'city4', 'city1', 'city2');

var citiesObject = {};

for (var x = 0; x < cities.length; x++)
{
    if (citiesObject[cities[x]])
    {
        citiesObject[cities[x]]++
    }
    else
    {
        citiesObject[cities[x]] = 1;
    }
}
```